# Word choice : Derelict / forsaken

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

> The building has been **derelict** for years; several sections of the roof
>   have fallen in.

Is it all right to use *derelict* in above sentence or it's incorrect and *forsaken* is better ? Perhaps *abandoned* would have been better but I don't have that to choose from as this is a question asked in my exam with just the options which I have mentioned above.

Comment: **Derelict** is the word I would use. It is used particularly for abandoned/uncared for/unmaintained buildings, see [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/derelict) for example.

Comment: @user212388 What do you find when you check the dictionary? For me, "derelict" and "abandoned" are about equally good. (For "derelict", the second half of the sentence would be illustrating the first, whereas for "abandoned", the second half of the sentence would be noting the consequence of the first.) "Forsaken" is very poetic/literary. Even in the 21st century the primary association for most English speakers is probably the Bible verse [Matthew 27:46](http://biblehub.com/matthew/27-46.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine:

- **[derelict](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/derelict)** (*adjective*) - Derelict buildings or places are not cared for and are in bad condition
- **[abandoned](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abandoned)** (*adjective*) - Left behind, or left without care and protection.
- **[abandon](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abandon)** (*verb*) - To leave a place, thing, or person, usually for ever
- **[forsaken](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/forsaken)** (*adjective*) - A place that is not lived in, used, or looked after.

Both words share a common meaning "**forsaken, given up by the natural owner or guardian**". However, "**derelict**" is very close to something like "**In a very poor condition as a result of disuse and abandonment/neglect**" while "**abandoned**" is closer to "**left empty or uninhabited**"

> A *building* can be **derelict** and **abandoned** altogether.

In your example you say that '*several sections of the roof have fallen in*' so in this case it can surely be **derelict** but is it **abandoned**? Outside of the question's options in a case where it would be abandoned because of being in a poor condition it would we wise to include both words in the sentence:

- The **derelict** building has been **abandoned** for years; several sections of the roof have fallen in.

However, as you have mentioned that you have only two options, I'd go for "**derelict**".

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this use of "derelict" feels *off* to me. I would prefer to use "abandoned", but I'm not certain why.  It may be due to what Luke Sawczak points out in his comment, that a "derelict" building is, *by definition*, falling apart, making the rest of the sentence redundant.  "Abandoned" simply means no one lives there, and so it's a natural consequence that the roof has fallen in.

But I think it's more the use of "has been" in the example, which suggests you meant to use the present perfect progressive.  You can't "derelict" something, but you can "abandon" it, so "has been abandoned" sounds somewhat more natural to my ears.

Also, an *abandoned* building can be quickly reoccupied, but a *derelict* building needs to be repaired before it can go back to not being derelict.  To some extent, the present perfect suggests a condition that could have easily changed any time, and a building can't easily go back and forth between "derelict" and "not derelict".

Perhaps this is just my personal (or *American*) style, and others have no problem with this use of "derelict".  Given no other options, it's fine, and better than "forsaken" (which I've never heard applied to a building).

Comment: I lean towards *abandoned* as well, though I don't think it's because the tense risks suggesting a passive. I think it's because it's hard to identify the moment from which something "has been derelict", but easy to pinpoint the moment from which it "has been abandoned". Also, for *forsaken* and buildings, we can't rule out poorly written fantasy MMORPGs. ;)

Comment: The semi-colon connects the explanation and details to the first part of the sentence, so even though *derelict* could mean "in a poor condition", and when applied to buildings, "falling into ruins", it's not specific; therefore the second part doesn't really repeat the first. *Derelict* in its original sense means "abandoned, forsaken". I don't know what you're trying to say in your second paragraph. Re your third paragraph: it depends on the state in which the abandoned building is for us or anyone to be able to assess its reoccupiability; after all, it was abandoned for a reason.

Comment: You'll find a great number of sentences written by native speakers of English if you google `"has been derelict for years"`, suggesting your intuition about the use of the present perfect with *derelict* is off the mark.

Comment: @userr2684291  This is more about the *nuance* of words than their *definition*.  "Derelict" is an evocative term that conveys a powerful image of neglect and decay -- you would not use it unless you meant to imply that the building is really in trouble.  Meaning "abandoned" suggests that no one has lived there for some time, but is more ambiguous about the state of decay.

Comment: @userr2684291 if you look at your Google results you'll notice many of the results are from UK sources.  I'm American, so that could account for my intuition.

Comment: @LukeSawczak "forsaken wilderness" or "forsaken castle" yes, but "building" seems too ordinary to merit being "forsaken".  :)

Comment: You can say "**A forsaken church**" or "**A forsaken monastery**" for instance.

Comment: I wouldn't apply this word "**forsaken**" to an ordinary building though. "**abandoned**" would seem like the best choice here. The semicolon gives extra information about what happened because of it being abandoned.

Comment: @SovereignSun or even "a forsaken *playground*".  Really anything that evokes a strong image

Comment: @Andrew I agree. Something so simple as a building can't be forsaken.

Comment: @SovereignSun ***Pedestrian***, that's the word I was looking for.  You would not apply "forsaken" to something as *pedestrian* as a "building".  At the very least you'd want to call it a "derelict *structure*"  :)